# Joomla Administrator login page error

Tags: joomla, authentication, administrator

This is in Joomla.Someone hacked mysite. I did ftp of all the files from the PC. Everything is working except the `domain.com/administrator` page. I am able to login to the Control Panel and use File Manager. Can I fix the `domain.com/administrator` page from the File Manager?

The error message is:

```
mark('afterLoad') : null; // Instantiate the application. 

$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator'); // Initialise the application. 

$app->initialise(array( 'language' => $app->getUserState('application.lang') )); // Mark afterIntialise in the profiler. 

JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null; // Route the application. 

$app->route(); // Mark afterRoute in the profiler. 

JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null; // Dispatch the application. 

$app->dispatch(); // Mark afterDispatch in the profiler. 

JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null; // Render the application. 

$app->render(); // Mark afterRender in the profiler.

JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null; // Return the response.

echo $app;
```

Comment: Friend where is the error message ? its just some code section ?

Comment: when I enter domain.com/administrator in the url then I am getting this message.

Comment: enable debug mode on from configuration.php on root , also you didn't customized admin login page then, upload fresh file from your Joomla version.If you can share your site url i can look well

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here it is post4city.com/administrator/

Comment: Reloaded files. Worked now. Able to see Administrator page. Thanks.